# Is there a tool to construct a higher order bezier curve?

Tags: math, bezier

Is there a tool to construct a higher order bezier curve? I want to obtain  a bouncing effect of a ball and all i can find right a now is tool for cubic-bezier (cubic-bezier.com).

Comment: Math? http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/doc/Bezier-curves.html

Answer (score 0):

There is, but your reason doesn't explain your question... why did you think a higher order bezier curve would help drawing a bouncing ball better? If, say, you want to generate a curve through some of the bounce-points, you want a Catmull-Rom spline instead, since that passes through points (the two spline forms are interchangeable, but they have different interpolation properties, with Catmull-Rom much more useful for things like trajectory rendering).